Ошибка при запуске бота на pythonanywhere
У меня есть телеграм бот, в котором есть requests.post().
При запуске телеграм бота на pythonanywhere выдаёт ошибку:

requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='мойсайт.ком', port=443): Max retries
exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

помогите пожалуйста исправить

По-моему тут 100500 таких вопросов было. Банят там ботов, в смысле не дают им коннектиться к телеге, если я правильно помню.
